# How do I inherit a child's property in css?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, gridview

I'm making a website using CSS gridview and I want to have the largest element in the row determine the height of the row. An example code segment would look something like this:

```
<div class="row-1">
    <div class="col-4" style="height: 40px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is for the row to inherit the height property of the first column.

Comment: I think you dhould edit your question to accept JS/jQuery answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.row-1 {
  display: flex;
}
.col-4 {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-1">
  <div class="col-4" style="height: 40px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
  </div>
</div>
```